# Error: Invalid value for <image> attribute when passing in variable

Tags: javascript, json, maps

I was having some problem when trying to zoom to certain point on esri base map with an OneMap map overlayer. Here is the function where I get the coordinates x and y by passing in postal code:

```
function zoomPostal(postalCode) {
 $.getJSON("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr" +
        "&searchVal=" + postalCode + "&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY" +
        "&returnGeom=0&rset=1", function (data) {

     var x =  data.SearchResults[1].X;
     console.log(x);
     var y =  data.SearchResults[1].Y;
     console.log(y);
    var loc = new esri.geometry.Point({ 
        "x": x, 
        "y": y, 
        "spatialReference":'PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]' });           

    map.centerAndZoom(loc, 5);
        });
```

}

When I print out the x and y, I am getting 23948.7465 and 47505.7986 so which means it is not NaN or null. However, with these code, I am getting error message as such:

```
Error: Invalid value for <image> attribute x="NaN" 
Error: Invalid value for <image> attribute y="NaN"
```

The strange thing is if I hardcoded the coordinate x and y to 'x" and "y" in the loc variable, it did zoomed and worked perfectly. I not sure why is it behaved in this way.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the part where the error message was show:

```
function zoomPostal(postalCode) {
 $.getJSON("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr" +
        "&searchVal=" + postalCode + "&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY" +
        "&returnGeom=0&rset=1", function (data) {

     var x =  data.SearchResults[1].X;
     console.log(x);
     var y =  data.SearchResults[1].Y;
     console.log(y);
    var loc = new esri.geometry.Point({ 
        "x": x, 
        "y": y, 
        "spatialReference":'PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]' });           
    console.log(loc.x);
    map.centerAndZoom(loc, 5);
        });
```

}

From these code, I am getting 23948.7465 and 47505.7986 for **variable x and y** and as well as **loc.x** when I print them out but the error message was there.

Then, I tried to **hardcode the x and y** by putting in the **value above** like this:

```
 function zoomPostal(postalCode) {
 $.getJSON("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr" +
        "&searchVal=" + postalCode + "&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY" +
        "&returnGeom=0&rset=1", function (data) {

     var x =  data.SearchResults[1].X;
     console.log(x);
     var y =  data.SearchResults[1].Y;
     console.log(y);
    var loc = new esri.geometry.Point({ 
        "x": 23948.7465, 
        "y": 47505.7986, 
        "spatialReference":'PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]' });           
    console.log(loc.x);
    map.centerAndZoom(loc, 5);
        });
```

}

With these code, the zoom works perfectly without any error.

Comment: Use Chrome developer tool and check what response you got. And show logs when you printed out the x and y.

Comment: @HiroakiMachida When I tried to print loc.x, I am getting the exact same value as my x. I just don't know why it could not take in the x but when I hardcoded the same coordinate for x and y, it works.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something. Is that error raised in map.centerAndZoom() function? If so, please paste the code of the function and which line raises errors.

Comment: The error raised when I declare the x for "x" and y for "y" inside the Point. It only worked when I hardcode the coordinate like 23948.7465 but not the x variable. As for the centerAndZoom, it was one of the API call provided by Esri.

Comment: Please show the "hardcode" code. And you said "When I tried to print loc.x, I am getting the exact same value as my x.", is this when you hardcode?

Comment: @HiroakiMachida I've edited the question already. Hope that it's clear

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
function zoomPostal(postalCode) {
 $.getJSON("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr" +
        "&searchVal=" + postalCode + "&otptFlds=SEARCHVAL,CATEGORY" +
        "&returnGeom=0&rset=1", function (data) {

     var x =  data.SearchResults[1].X;
     console.log(x);
     var y =  data.SearchResults[1].Y;
     console.log(y);
     var initializer = { "x": x, "y": y, "spatialReference":'PROJCS["SVY21",GEOGCS["SVY21[WGS84]",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]' }
    var loc = new esri.geometry.Point(initializer);           
    console.log(loc.x);
    map.centerAndZoom(loc, 5);
        });
}
```

Comment: Nope, does not work. Is it because it is a double or something but not a variable?

Comment: I've tested it already. You have to parseFloat the variable x and y because of the NaN error